# How to store values in an array, traversing the tree?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-tree

So I have a binaryTree and I would like to store the values inside of each nodes, in an array. I tried to solve my problem in this way, however, everytime the function getAllElements() is used, the size of this.root.arrayOfObj increases. It shouldn't. Or if it should, it should because I have added or removed a node in the binaryTree. I tried to not use the arrays from the root and instead creating a local variable, but in this way I am not able to save all the objects from all the nodes in the tree.

```
class node {
    node left, right;
    <T>genericObject;
    <T> ArrayList arrayOfObjs = new ArrayList<>();
    <T>array_objects[];
    node(){
    left = null;
    right = null;

}

class binarytree {
    Node root;

    binarytree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public <T>[] getAllElements(Node t) {
        this.root.array_objects = null;
        
        if (t == null) {
            return this.root.array_objects;
        } else {
            this.root.arrayOfObjs.add(t.genericObject);
        }
        
        getAllElements(t.left);
        getAllElements(t.right);

        this.root.array_objects = new <T>[t.arrayOfObjs.size()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < t.arrayOfObjs.size(); i++) {
            this.root.array_object[i] = this.root.arrayOfObjs.get(i);
        }

        return this.root.array_objects;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Abra (this is not the real code, but is similar to what i am working on), the class node has also the constructor where left, and right are null.

Comment: @Abra, because I haven't checked it correctly. As I said, this is not the real code, it's a generic form of my real code.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125279/storing-binary-tree-into-an-array

Comment: @Abra I tried, but it doesn't work. Because I am not returning an integer value with the function getAllElements. I am returning an <T> array[]; (Also i had problems in the compilation, it didn't compile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my definition of class `Node` that does compile for me.

```java
class Node<T> {
    Node<T> left, right;
    T genericObject;
}
```

Based on the above, here is my implementation of method `getAllElements()`.

```java
public void getAllElements(Node<T> aNode, List<T> list) {
    if (aNode == null) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        getAllElements(aNode.left, list);
        list.add(aNode.genericObject);
        getAllElements(aNode.right, list);
    }
}
```

You cannot create a generic array, so while this will compile...

```java
T array_objects[];
```

This will not:

```java
array_objects = new T[50];
```

Hence you can use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) rather than an array since you can always convert a `List` into an array.

Comment: thanks for the correction, but i don't think that node needs to have the type. in my implementation, is just node, with the left, right node and the arrays, arraylist and the genericObject.